Architecture react-app and nginx. How to properly deploy react-app?
I’m building an architecture for heavily loaded services and I’m not entirely sure what a React application in conjunction with Nginx should do.
For example: The user knocks on Nginx at the URL. Nginx, acting as a proxy, redirects the request to the React application.
Does the React app somehow need to be deployed as a web server? (serve / nodejs express / next.js) And if you need to access data in the database, then use nodejs methods to access the backend?
Nginx can also be configured as a web server for distributing static files. But how then to send a request to the backend and process the response...
Moreover, each cube is a separate docker container.
Question: How do I need to deploy a react application in my case? As a separate webservice?
enter image description here
I tried deploying react-app without any additional libraries in docker and running it using serve.
But I didn't succeed. The site reads, but there are some problems with routing. But that's not the question.

Commonly react SPA is just a collection of static assets and should be deployed the same way as any other static website. A webserver needs to be configured for SPA in order for client-side router to work correctly. It's unknown what's react app in your case and how it can differ
